# communication between iframe using postMessage

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I'm trying to remove buttons from a screen that I access with an iframe so that my parent software doesn't make changes through the buttons. To do this, I am using postMessage communication to inform a variable in the ifram's child application, but in this application the change to the variable that I send is not happening.

The code is javascript, so there is no debugging, so I am using consoleLogs to see what is coming to the console. And I haven't found the update yet.

FOR SENDING:

```
const sendBooleanToIframe = () => {
    const iframe = frameRef.current
    if (iframe) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        iframe.contentWindow?.postMessage({ yourBooleanVariable: true }, '*')
      }, 3000)
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    const iframeLoadHandler = () => {
      sendBooleanToIframe()
    }
    const iframe = frameRef.current
    if (iframe) {
      iframe.addEventListener('load', iframeLoadHandler)
    }
    return () => {
      if (iframe) {
        iframe.removeEventListener('load', iframeLoadHandler)
      }
    }
}, [])
```

FOR RECEIVED:

```
setTimeout(() => {
 useEffect(() => {
  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    console.log('start handleMessage diagnostics')
   if (event.data.yourBooleanVariable) {
    console.log('Menssage iframe:', event.data.yourBooleanVariable)
    headerInfo = false
   }
  };
  window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage)
  return () => {
   window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage)
  }
 }, [])
} , 3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

First `useEffect()` can not be in a setTimeout function.

Second in React the event handlers should be added via the html in your function.

```html
<iframe src=“” onload={sendBooleanToIframe} />
```

Third the receive function should be in your base app code, not inside a React function. It binds to `window` and needs to be set up in the first JS event loop on the page, as after this the `onload` event in the parent will fire. You don’t need to wait for React to render the rest of the page.

Forth you should not need any `setTimeout()` calls when using `postMessage()`.

Fifth all the main browsers have JS debuggers in them. The best on is in Chrome.

Comment: I have hit many times that even in `onload` callback the iframe is still not ready to receive message so I need to `setTimeout()` in `onload` callback to make sure iframe can get the message. I can't figure out why.

Comment: You need the message event listerner in the iframe to be setup in the first JS event loop. I tend to put it in its own small `<script>` block to ensure it is the first thing to be run.

Comment: But the event listener in iframe needs to get a message first in order to reply to it. So the parent window needs to keep sending iframe message until it gets a reply. So what I was saying was there seems to no good timing for the parent window to just sent the first "ping" message just once.

Comment: The onload event in the parent fires after the first event loop runs in the iframe.

Comment: If the iframe is a static html onload works but if iframe is SPA onload won't work. I have tried this many times.

Comment: It's failing in your SPA, because you're not creating the message event listener in the first event cycle. You're calling it too late. The problem is you have it in a component and not in the SPA startup code.